# XQuery: extract all nested xs:attributeGroup

Tags: xquery, basex

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="personattr">
  <xs:attribute name="attr1" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="attr2" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="personattr2">
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:attributeGroup name="personattr2">
  <xs:attribute name="attr12" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="attr22" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="personattr3">
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:attributeGroup name="personattr3">
  <xs:attribute name="attr13" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="attr23" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:attributeGroup name="personattr4">
  <xs:attribute name="attr14" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="attr24" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

Given the sample XSD file above, how do I extract all nested attributeGroup starting from a specific attributeGroup? From `personattr` there is a `personattr2` inside. Inside `personattr2` there is `personattr3`. The result shouldn't contain `personattr4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily by decending into the referenced child groups with a recursive *user-defined function*:

```
declare function local:groups-below($groups, $name) {
  $name,
  for $ref in $groups[@name = $name]/xs:attributeGroup/@ref/string()
  return local:groups-below($groups, $ref)
};

local:groups-below($all-groups, 'personattr')
```

This returns the following group names:

```
personattr
personattr2
personattr3
```

If you want the whole elements instead, just return those instead of their names:

```
declare function local:groups-below($groups, $name) {
  let $group := $groups[@name = $name]
  return (
    $group,
    for $ref in $group/xs:attributeGroup/@ref/string()
    return local:groups-below($groups, $ref)
  )
};

local:groups-below($all-groups, 'personattr')
```

This returns the following sequence:

```
<xs:attributeGroup xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="personattr">
  <xs:attribute name="attr1" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="attr2" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="personattr2"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>,
<xs:attributeGroup xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="personattr2">
  <xs:attribute name="attr12" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="attr22" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="personattr3"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>,
<xs:attributeGroup xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="personattr3">
  <xs:attribute name="attr13" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="attr23" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `local:groups-below(//attributeGroup, 'personattr')` ?

Comment: The input given in the question is not a valid XML node, so I assumed that it is a sequence bound to some variable (here `$all-groups`). You also only need the top-level `xs:attributeGroup` elements, not the ones with `@ref` attributes. But if the whole *XSD* document is the context item, then `local:groups-below(//xs:attributeGroup, 'personattr')` would return the correct result.

Comment: Actually what I want is all xs:attributeGroup node returning as a sequence. In this case, attributeGroup with name personattr, personattr2, personattr3 in a sequence. Anyway I will give you credits

Comment: I have extended my answer to also show how to return the `xs:attributeGroup` elements themselves.

Comment: I dont understand your code. Function local:groups-below returns a sequence. Isn't the final result a nested sequence, like (personattr, (personattr2, (personattr3)))?

Comment: There are no nested sequences in XQuery, all sequences are *flattened*.